# Ajax loading seems to be more updated than the actual home page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, homepage, caching

I've noticed a strange little issue, which is most likely related to caching.

When I'm on the homepage of a Stack Exchange site (not on Stack Overflow), it would occationally tell me that there's new activity, and that I should click the banner to update:

[image: Example]

When clicked:

[image: After click]

However, when I refresh the page, I still get the outdated, cached version of the page for several minutes.

[image: After refresh]

---

If the information about an update is available, shouldn't that invalidate the cache? I mean, the server *knows for sure* that there's new content available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal; the page is cached on the server for a while.

However, if you *click on the banner* instead, the new posts will be loaded inline into the page. The ajax loading call doesn't have to wait for the page cache to be updated, it simply updates the HTML page already loaded into your browser with the new posts.

The server can cache the page more aggressively, *because* this feature is available. People that care about getting the newest questions the fastest, use the AJAX loader. This gives the server more breathing room; home pages use a lot of queries to build and are in heavy demand.

New or updated questions, on the other hand, probably are already cached separately (when posted, edited or answered) making it relatively simple to implement the web socket feature *without having to query the backend database*.

Comment: That's the point, if you *know* for sure that there is more update content, shouldn't that invalidate the cache? I'm not talking about client-side cache, but about server-side one.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: If only all web development was that simple.

Comment: It's really not that difficult actually.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Are you taking into account load patterns and query costs? It's never just about how to build the page.

Comment: But the query was already preformed, when the Ajax thing loaded the new questions...

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: No, new questions were posted (inserts) that have been added to a cache perhaps. To build the full page, *new* queries have to be issued. For all we know the AJAX calls make *no* SQL queries at all?

Comment: If it makes no SQL queries at all... Where does it get the information from?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: When I post a question or add an answer, I POST to the server. That information can be added to a in-memory cache and trigger websockets to show that a new question has been posted or that a question just saw activity (depending on the sort), as well as being inserted into the database.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I don't **know** this for certain, but it makes sense from a performance perspective. Why ask the database for new questions when users provide your application with up-to-date information as to what is new *all the time*? To be explicit: **I am not a SE employee, nor have I seen how things are actually implemented**. But I am a web dev with plenty of scalability experience.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Martijn is correct, the websockets data comes from an event model pushed through redis to our websocket servers as part of the post insert/edit pipeline...it in no way re-runs homepage queries.  Also note that there are combo tag pages, so you'd have to traverse the cache just to see what to clear, which can be thousands of pages.